# Selenium click button Python

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, popup

I want to close popup windows in Selenium (Python). The button called "joyride-close-tip" is working and closes itself, but the other two don't. Why not? What is wrong?

I copied the name of buttons, so the names are correct.

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver
gumbi = ["joyride-close-tip","close lib-popup-button-close", "iCDacceptallbtn lib-cc-accept-all"]
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(webpage)
for gumb in gumbi: 
    time.sleep(5)
    click_button = driver.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value= gumb)
    click_button.click()
```

[image]
This one is working.

[image]
[image]

These two are not working.

What is wrong? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Try Changing This line From Your Code....

```
gumbi = ["joyride-close-tip","close lib-popup-button-close", "iCDacceptallbtn lib-cc-accept-all"]
```

TO This.

```
gumbi = ["joyride-close-tip","lib-popup-button-close", "lib-cc-accept-all"]
```

Because The `By.CLASS_NAME` method of selenium only accept single class name, where in `gumbi` list, first ele is only single class name and other two has 2 class names so after removing this, may help you...